# Referencing columns in a ROWTYPE table

Tags: postgresql, rowtype

In PostgreSQL I would like to dynamically access columns in a `ROWTYPE` by referencing a column number.

I would for example like to access column number 59, by for example `r.column(59)`, instead of `r.columnname`. Is this possible?

The purpose is that i want loop through a number of columns and dont want to hard code all columns.

For example:

```
r data.stageing_table%rowtype;

FOR r IN SELECT * FROM data.stage_table LOOP
   INSERT INTO TABLE XXX
   .....
   VALUES(r.column(8))

END LOOP
```

Is it possible to access columns in my rowtype result set?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK you can't, but you can do something that maybe is close enough. You could fetch position of column in relation and alias it to that number (prefixed with non numerical char). You would have to declare your variable as `record` instead.

Example on pg_attribute system table:

```
DO $$
DECLARE
  l_row record;
  l_query text := $q$ SELECT %s
                        FROM pg_attribute
                       WHERE attrelid = 'pg_attribute'::regclass
                  $q$;
BEGIN
  FOR l_row IN EXECUTE format(l_query, --below is value that goes into %s placeholder
                              (SELECT string_agg(concat(attname, ' AS c', attnum), ', ')
                                 FROM pg_attribute
                                WHERE attrelid = 'pg_attribute'::regclass
                                  AND attnum > 0)
                             )
  LOOP
    RAISE NOTICE 'Attname: % is column number %', l_row.c2, l_row.c6;
  END LOOP;
END;
$$;
```

Query that actually gets executed is:

```
SELECT attrelid AS c1, attname AS c2, atttypid AS c3, attstattarget AS c4,
       attlen AS c5, attnum AS c6, attndims AS c7, attcacheoff AS c8,
       atttypmod AS c9, attbyval AS c10, attstorage AS c11, attalign AS c12,
       attnotnull AS c13, atthasdef AS c14, attidentity AS c15, attisdropped AS c16,
       attislocal AS c17, attinhcount AS c18, attcollation AS c19, attacl AS c20,
       attoptions AS c21, attfdwoptions AS c22
  FROM pg_attribute
 WHERE attrelid = 'pg_attribute'::regclass
```

You can get total number of columns from `pg_attribute` table, remembering that those that have attnum < 0 are **hidden** system columns, so don't count them. I suppose you could just take `max(attnum)` or `l_columns := array_agg(concat(attname, ' AS c', attnum), ', ');` and then `array_length(l_columns,1)` for count and `array_to_string(l_columns,', ')` to get column list for dynamic SQL.